# Git says file too big to push, file doesn't exist in repo

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a large project that I am working on that does a lot of things I am unfamiliar with. One thing is making caches. I do not want these in the git repo, so I deleted them and committed.

I did a few more commits, and occasionally deleted caches, then finally just made a .gitignore for the project. When I went to push this last commit, I get an error saying certain files are too big for git (over 100 MB)

It says a certain file (folder/folder/cacheFile) is causing the error. The thing is, that file does not exist. I cannot see it, or delete it. I tried removing the .gitignore and rebuilding project then committing, and when I go to push I get the same cache causing problems (the original ones that I cannot find as they do not exist)

Comment: You need to extirpate it from the commit history.

Comment: Can you clarify how/ what I would be doing?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

Comment: My best guess is you deleted `cacheFile` in a previous commit, but are only now pushing it.